# Custom @RolesAllowed roles in Jersey WebService with ContainerRequestFilter

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs, servlet-filters

I created a filter with ContainerRequestFilter interface and try to assign custom roles that returning user entity.

```
 @Override
public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) {
    User user = authenticate(request);
    if (user != null) {
        request.setSecurityContext(new Authorizer(user));
    } else {
        throw new WebApplicationException(400);
    }
    return request;

}

 private User authenticate(ContainerRequest request) {

    user = new User("erhan", "customRole");


    return user;
}

public class Authorizer implements SecurityContext {

    private User user;
    private Principal principal;

    public Authorizer(final User user) {
        this.user = user;
        this.principal = new Principal() {

            public String getName() {
                return user.username;
            }
        };
    }

    public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
        return this.principal;
    }

    public boolean isUserInRole(String role) {
        return (role.equals(user.role));
    }

    public boolean isSecure() {
        return "https".equals(uriInfo.getRequestUri().getScheme());
    }

    public String getAuthenticationScheme() {
        return SecurityContext.BASIC_AUTH;
    }
}

public class User {

    public String username;
    public String role;

    public User(String username, String role) {
        this.username = username;
        this.role = role;
    }
}
```

Everything is fine with that filter, but when it goes to web service

```
 @GET
 @RolesAllowed({"customRole"})
 @Path("/test")
 public String getByType(@Context HttpHeaders headers,@Context SecurityContext sc,
                                 @Context HttpServletRequest request) {



   return null;
 }
```

it reaches the webservice but when i change role,still reached the same webservice. How can i provide different custom roles in Jersey ?

Comment: Ok i think i found the solution but should be different way 

just add 

      <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ResourceFilters</param-name>
            <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.RolesAllowedResourceFilterFactory</param-value>
        </init-param>

filter to my web.xml solved problem. But Why i need to initialize one more filter else ContainerRequestFilters ?

Comment: Because Jersey doesn't support @RolesAllowed out of the box. Mentioned filter adds this support. And BTW, you should not return 400 for unauthorized, it means bad request. See HTTP status 401.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Jersey 2 you can just register `RolesAllowedDynamicFeature` and secure your application in `web.xml`. Than you don't need custom `SecurityContext` implementation.

See [Jersey custom SecurityContext on EJB jax-rs resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26518941/jersey-custom-securitycontext-on-ejb-jax-rs-resource) for details about that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put annotation to the class.
For me adding [@PreMatching](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs-javax.jax-rs/2.0.1/javax/ws/rs/container/PreMatching.html) with [@Provider](https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/javax/ws/rs/ext/Provider.html) works. 
It seems that Provider annotation is mandatory in this case.

```
@PreMatching
@Provider
public class RequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
   .....
}
```

If this does not work try to add this:
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHORIZATION)

Additionally you need to enables roles and [register  RolesAllowedDynamicFeature](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/security.html) or use [alternatives - check example 19.2](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/entity-filtering.html)